# Exact figure size in matplotlib with title, axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

Similar questions have been asked before, but all of my search results don't 
address my problem.  Take the following example code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
fig = figure(1, figsize=(3.25, 3))
plot([0,1,5,2,9])
title('title')
xlabel('xAxis')
ylabel('yAxis')
fig.savefig('test.png',dpi=600)
```

The resulting figure is 2040x1890 pixels, or 3.4"x3.15", and the x-label
is cut off.  Looking at the PNG file in an image editor, it appears that 
the axes and tick labels fit the desired size.  I've tried taking the 
difference from the output size and requested size and feeding that back 
in (3.25 - (3.4-3.25) = 3.10, but matplotlib seems to add an arbitrary 
buffer and it still doesn't come out to the desired size.  How does one 
make an overall figure that is the desired size?

Comment: I can't reproduce this- when I run this code on my machine and open the PNG in Preview, I get a figure that is 1950x1800 pixels, or exactly 3.25 by 3 inches. What version of matplotlib are you using? ETA: Though I do see that the xlabel is cut off.

Comment: My matplotlib version is 1.0.1 - I'lll try updating to 1.1.0.  A bit of wierdness: <code> In [228]: fig = figure(3, figsize=(3.15, 3.15))
        In [229]: fig.savefig('test0.png',dpi=600)
        In [230]: fig.get_size_inches()
        Out[230]: array([ 3.3,  3.3])
<\code>

Comment: The above behavior persists in mpl 1.1.0 on IPython 0.11, Python 2.7.2 (x32 version) on Win7 x64.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In agreement with the comment from David Robinson, the figure produced here is 3.25 by 3 inches as measured by photoshop, although the xlabel does show cut-off (mpl 1.1.0 in python 2.6 64-bit, win7)

A solution to overcome the problem is to manually adjust the margins with `subplot_adjust`:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
fig = figure(1, figsize=(3.25, 3))
plot([0, 1, 5, 2, 9])
title('title')
xlabel('xAxis')
ylabel('yAxis')
subplots_adjust(bottom=0.14)   # <--
fig.savefig('test.png', dpi=600)
```

The default value of these margins are set in the matploblibrc file and you can modify it there permanently. The default value for the bottom margin in my case was 0.10.

Either if your figure is of a wrong size or correct, as in my case, you can use subplot_adjust to provide enough space for the label. Then if needed, you can calculate the correction to get the actual picture or figure size you want as you already did.

The final view of the saved figure depends on the size of that figure. If you `show()` your figure and you save it from the matplotlib view frame you get the label cut-off in the image. But if you increase manually the size of the image you will see the label appearing and if you save it then it will also appear in the saved image. Lets say that is WYSIWYG. Your figure is of a very small size and this makes your label to get cut. So another approach is to make a bigger figure maybe with lower dpi to keep overall size. This also works:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
fig = figure(1, figsize=(6.5, 6))   # <---
plot([0, 1, 5, 2, 9])
title('title')
xlabel('xAxis')
ylabel('yAxis')
fig.savefig('test.png', dpi=300)    # <---
```

In any case, I would consider this as a matplolib bug, as you could expect to have an uncut figure after plot and save.

Answer (score 8):

matplotlib 1.1.1 has added `figure.tight_layout()` ([doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html)) that will do this for you.

Comment: They moved `tight_layout()` in a different page of the docs because it's not a figure attribute anymore. You can find it [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html)

Comment: However, there is a [`set_tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_tight_layout) method in `figure`.