# Saving figure with exact pixel size

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I declare in python the pixel size (height and width) in which I want to save a figure (not just dpi, the exact number of pixels)? I've seen a lot of similar questions, but quite old and none of them seems to work ([example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491314/python-save-matplotlib-figure-with-exact-pixel-size) [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels)).

I would also like to know if by doing so it's possible to change the aspect ratio of an image? I have a 11227x11229 pixels image, I would like to open it in python and save it as a 11230x11229, but so far can't achieve it.

Right now this is how I save my image, but I have to play with the "dpi" setting to approach the desired resolution. It's tedious, I can't always have the exact resolution and I can't change the aspect ratio like intended:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, hspace = 0, wspace = 0)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(superpositionFINAL)
plt.savefig('myImage.png',  bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0, dpi=2807.8)
plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: It totally depends on what graphics / imaging module you are using (but you have not specified in your question or its tags).

Comment: I have edit with the code I use to display and save the image, does that help ? I'm willing to change how I do it of course if anyone have a solution using something else ^^

Comment: You could create the image a little larger than you need (so you have sufficient quality) then resize it using PIL/Pillow or OpenCV in Python,  or just with **ImageMagick** in the Terminal `magick INPUT.PNG -resize '11230x11229!' RESULT.PNG`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try some resizing with pil/pillow or opencv. Just a question, I saw number of times suggestion about commands in the "terminal" like that. What is the "terminal" and how can I access it please ? Sorry I'm beginner

Comment: It's called **Command Prompt** if you are on Windows and in that case the command is `magick INPUT.PNG -resize 11230x11229! RESULT.PNG`

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, so far I only managed to have an error saying the name "magick" is unknown, not sure if I'm using it right

Comment: If you have an older version 6 ImageMagick, you'd need `convert INPUT....` rather than `magick INPUT ...`.

Comment: Or you may not have set your PATH correctly to include the directory where ImageMagick is installed.

Comment: Or more obviously, you haven't installed ImageMagick at all.

Comment: You can do it with the Pillow fork of the `PIL` (Python Graphics Library) which you can get via [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/). Note you can download & install it via `pip` (see [installation instructions](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)). Note that using it does not involve the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to "accept as answer" the comments under my posts? So I just write the answer here. It's by using the PIL package that @martineau and @Mark Setchell suggested that it worked like a charm:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('myImage.png')
newsize = (11230, 11229)
img = img.resize(newsize)
img.save('myResizedImage.png')
```

Comment: Well done. You can't accept a comment as an answer, so you did the right thing. You can, and should, accept your own answer too.

Comment: The website tell me I have to wait 24h, I'll do it tomorrow ;)
Thanks for the explanation and help !

Answer (score 1):

You can do some math to figure out the DPI you need for a given figure size. Suppose your figure is 6.4in x 4.8in, and you want an image that is 640px x 480px, you know your DPI needs to be 100:

```
def export_fig(fig, filename, width, **kwrgs):
    figsize = fig.get_size_inches()
    dpi = width / figsize[0]
    fig.savefig(filename, dpi=dpi, **kwargs)
```

I provided a `**kwargs` in this function that just passes any keyword arguments to `fig.savefig()`.

To use this function:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 500)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.4, 4.8))
plt.plot(x, y)

export_fig(fig, "./export.png", 640)
```

which gives you this image, with the correct dimensions:

[image]

[image]

If you find that your images have the wrong aspect ratio, you simply need to correct the figure size before exporting it as an image.

```
def resize_width_to_aspect_ratio(fig, desired_aspect_ratio):
    old_width, height = fig.get_size_inches()
    new_width = desired_aspect_ratio * current_size[1]
    fig.set_size_inches((new_width, height))
```

Since your desired aspect ratio is `11230:11229`, you'd use this function like so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, hspace = 0, wspace = 0)
plt.axis('off')
resize_width_to_aspect_ratio(fig, 11230/11229)
plt.imshow(superpositionFINAL)
export_fig(fig, "myImage.png", 11230, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.show()
```