# Plot size changes on saving plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted a graph with 14 subplots in matplotlib. In the window the plot looks like this-[image]

I save this plot using following command-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.savefig('img.png')
```

But the image that is saved looked like this-
[image]

Notice that the x axis labels get overlapped because the image is shrinked. The savefig() function has optional argument **dpi**, but it changes the resolution/quality of saved plot.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels), but it is used to improve image resolution.

I want the axis labels to be nicely spaced as in the window. Thanks

Comment: Do you want only a `.png` file? If not have your tried `.pdf` ?

Comment: Yes, I want the .png . I found the solutions and posted it as well

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I found the solution myself and posting it here for anyone who might face similar problem. I changed the figure size before saving and following code does the trick-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig =plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(20, 11,dpi=100)
plt.savefig('img.png')
```

Comment: Thanks! I was having the same problem and couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong :)