# Why is .imshow() producing images with more pixels than I have put in?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a `numpy` array **`A`**, having a shape of `(60,60,3)`, and I am using:

```
plt.imshow(  A,
             cmap          = plt.cm.gist_yarg,
             interpolation = 'nearest',
             aspect        = 'equal',
             shape         = A.shape
             )
plt.savefig( 'myfig.png' )
```

When I examine the `myfig.png` file, I see that it is 1200x800 pixels (in color).

What's going on here? I was expecting a 60x60 RGB image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib` doesn't work directly with pixels but rather a figure size (in inches) and a resolution (dots per inch, `dpi`)

So, you need to explicitly give a figure size and dpi. For example, you could set your figure size to 1x1 inches, then set the dpi to 60, to get a 60x60 pixel image.

You also have to remove the whitespace around the plot area, which you can do with `subplots_adjust`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))

A = np.random.rand(60,60,3)

plt.imshow(A,
           cmap=plt.cm.gist_yarg,
           interpolation='nearest',
           aspect='equal',
           shape=A.shape)

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0,right=1,bottom=0,top=1)

plt.savefig('myfig.png',dpi=60)
```

That creates this figure:

[image]

Which has a size of 60x60 pixels:

```
$ identify myfig.png 
myfig.png PNG 60x60 60x60+0+0 8-bit sRGB 8.51KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

You might also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels), which has lots of good information about figure sizes and resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Because `plt.savefig` renders a picture from your data and has an option `dpi`, dots per inch, it is set to some default value. You can change the quality of your figure by doing `plt.savefig('myfig.png', dpi=100)`

Comment: This still give me a png file with 1200 x 800 pixels.

Answer (score -1):

### Genuine Matplotlib Engine is highly abstract, while Renderers ...

As an initial remark, **`matplotlib`** toolbox helps to create a lot of 2D / 3D plotting with also **having a support for composing** smart overlays from **`pixmap-DataSET`**-s

<sub>( "***pictures***" could be imagined as a `{3D`[for **`RGB`**] | `4D`[for **`RGBA`**] `}-colourspace` data in `pixmap-DataSet`-s with `2D-[x,y]`-mapping of colours onto *"2D-paper"* )</sub>

**So one can overlay / view  / save** `pixmap-DataSET` **pictures**  via `matplotlib` methods.

---

### How to make `pixmap` size settings then?

For ***"picture"*** objects, that are rather "special" to the unconstrained world of unlimited numerical `precision` and any-depth `LevelOfDetail` in **`matplotlib`**, there are a few settings, that come into account at the very end of the processing lifecycle - at the output-generation moment.

So,
`matplotlib` can instruct it's (pre)selected **`Renderer`**
to produce final graphical output
at a special **typographic density** ... aka **`dpi = 60`** dots-per-inch
**and**
 also give an **overall sizing** ... **`figsize = ( 1, 1 )`** which makes your 60 x 60 image exactly 60x60 pixels ( once you spend a bit more effort to enforce `matplotlib` to disable all edges and other layout-specific surroundings )

---

The overlay composition may also use **`.figimage()`** method, where one can additionally specify `x0 = x_PX_OFFSET` and `y0 = y_PX_OFFSET` details about where to start *placing* a *picture* data within a given `figsize * dpi` pixel-mapping area.