# How to make a heatmap using Matplotlib with a specific pixel size for each cell?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I can easily make my heatmap using

```
data = np.random.rand(4,4)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However as you can see each cell is rectangular and I'd like each one to be square (32 x 32 pixels), generating a 512 x 512 pixel image.

Is there a way of forcing the plot (or each individual cell) to be of a specific pixel size?

**Edits**:

- my screen DPI is 100
- I'd like the actual heatmap to be 512 x 512 and
  **not** the entire figure

Comment: do you want to retain the tick marks and labels outside that 512x512 space?

Comment: not really, those would be unnecessary -- added a few more details in OP

Answer (score 1):

If you only want an image containing colors associated with your values and no tick marks or labels, I would suggest using [PIL.Image.fromarray](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray) from the [Pillow fork of PIL](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/index.html). you'll need to tile your array so each value is repeated 32x32 then create your image probably using float32 [mode](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) or int32 mode.. `im = PIL.Image.fromarray(ndarray, mode='f')`

PIL also allows you to resize an image, so you could create the image with one pixel per bin then [resize](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) with no per pixel re-sampling: `im.resize((512,512),resample=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm quoting from a previous post attached below:

> Matplotlib doesn't work with pixels directly, but rather physical
>   sizes and DPI. If you want to display a figure with a certain pixel
>   size, you need to know the DPI of your monitor. For example this link
>   will detect that for you.
>
> If you have an image of 3841x7195 pixels it is unlikely that you
>   monitor will be that large, so you won't be able to show a figure of
>   that size (matplotlib requires the figure to fit in the screen, if you
>   ask for a size too large it will shrink to the screen size). Let's
>   imagine you want an 800x800 pixel image just for an example. Here's
>   how to show an 800x800 pixel image in my monitor (my_dpi=96):
>
> plt.figure(figsize=(800/my_dpi, 800/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi) So you
>   basically just divide the dimensions in inches by your DPI.
>
> If you want to save a figure of a specific size, then it is a
>   different matter. Screen DPIs are not so important anymore (unless you
>   ask for a figure that won't fit in the screen). Using the same example
>   of the 800x800 pixel figure, we can save it in different resolutions
>   using the dpi keyword of savefig. To save it in the same resolution as
>   the screen just use the same dpi:
>
> plt.savefig('my_fig.png', dpi=my_dpi) To to save it as an 8000x8000
>   pixel image, use a dpi 10 times larger:
>
> plt.savefig('my_fig.png', dpi=my_dpi * 10) Note that the setting of
>   the DPI is not supported by all backends. Here, the PNG backend is
>   used, but the pdf and ps backends will implement the size differently.
>   Also, changing the DPI and sizes will also affect things like
>   fontsize. A larger DPI will keep the same relative sizes of fonts and
>   elements, but if you want smaller fonts for a larger figure you need
>   to increase the physical size instead of the DPI.
>
> Getting back to your example, if you want to save a image with 3841 x
>   7195 pixels, you could do the following:
>
> plt.figure(figsize=(3.841, 7.195), dpi=100) ( your code ...)
>   plt.savefig('myfig.png', dpi=1000) Note that I used the figure dpi of
>   100 to fit in most screens, but saved with dpi=1000 to achieve the
>   required resolution. In my system this produces a png with 3840x7190
>   pixels -- it seems that the DPI saved is always 0.02 pixels/inch
>   smaller than the selected value, which will have a (small) effect on
>   large image sizes. Some more discussion of this here.

[Specifying and saving a figure with exact size in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels)

Hope it helps!