# how to control wordcloud picture size

Tags: python, word-cloud

I just want to save a simple wordcloud in a file 200x150px but am getting 640x480 pixel instead. What am I doing wrong?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
cloud = WordCloud(width=200,height=150)
plt.imshow(cloud.generate_from_frequencies(t))
plt.savefig('c.png')
plt.clf()
```

Comment: You can see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels

Comment: would you care to post this as an answer? it solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to save the figure with the exact required number of pixel you can see the post about [Specifying and saving a figure with exact size in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels).

It will give you:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
cloud = WordCloud(width=200/my_dpi,height=150/my_dpi)
plt.imshow(cloud.generate_from_frequencies(t))
plt.savefig('c.png', dpi=my_dpi)
plt.clf()
```

with the value of `my_dpi` equal to the dpi of your monitor. You can find it following this [link](https://www.infobyip.com/detectmonitordpi.php) for example.

Comment: so my_dpi = 96 for example :-) Thanks for the solution! Even though the pyplot approach seems to be braindamaged. But maybe I am missing their motivation altogether.

Comment: Nice. Perfect scaling, used 200dpi for inserting into document. Tried several other things. Changing width and height on wordcloud didnt change anything. changing plt figsize = (20,10)  created a big white picture without any content.