# resize image to 224 pixels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-size, vgg-net

I want to use matplotlib to save images. Right now I use fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4)), this make images 288 x 288 pixels. How to change the image to 224 x 224 pixels and do not need to resize when fitting VGG model. I use matplotlib.pyplot.imsave to save image

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels)

Comment: `matplotlib` is used to **plot**.. it has nothing to do with resizing images. You can use PIL package instead as done in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using fig.savefig to save.
You set a figure size of 4 inch by 4 inch, so to get 224x224 pixels you need to set a dpi of 224/4 = 56:

```
    fig.savefig("$path", dpi=56)
```

Comment: I am using plt.imsave