# How to get the height of each bar in pixels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to get the height of each bar in a barplot in matplotlib in pixels? I can easily get values In a list but actually I need the height of the bars to be in pixels.
My output should be the containing list of heights of each bar in pixels and a plot.
Is it possible?

Here is reproducible example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
langs = ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python', 'PHP']
students = [23,17,35,29,12]
ax.bar(langs,students)
hth = []
for i in ax.patches:
    hth.append(i.get_height())
print(hth)
plt.show()
```

Output [23, 17, 35, 29, 12]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels

Comment: Your code returns the `height`, but the question text asks about the `width`. Which one is it? Also, what exactly do you need the values in pixels for? Unless you also know the position, it might not be too useful?

Comment: Than you for noticing. I edited my question. I need height not width. I need those heights in pixels because I am making a custom barplot in photoshop and i want to keep the same ratio if it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possible ways to get the bar height in pixels. One option is to draw the canvas, then use the window extent of the bars:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
langs = ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python', 'PHP']
students = [23,17,35,29,12]
bars = ax.bar(langs, students)
fig.canvas.draw()
r = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
heights = [bar.get_window_extent(r).height for bar in bars]
print(heights)
```