# How to save a matplotlib.pypot figure as an image with required pixel size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted `matplotlib.pyplot` plot. I have already removed the axes and title of the plot such that in jupyter notebook it looks like an image.

But I need to save that plot as an image to my local disk with required pixel resolution. In my case it's 40 X 98.

I have tried `plt.savefig` but I can't get the measurements accurately. I have provided my code snippet below. (spectrum) is my 2D array which is to be plotted as a fucntion of x and y axes.

```
spect = 20 * np.log10(spectrum)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1,1))
ax = sns.heatmap(spect,cmap='viridis',cbar=False,xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.savefig('sample.png',bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting the `dpi` argument in `savefig`. From the docs:
"dpi : the resolution in dots per inch".
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

The actual number of pixels may vary depending on your screen resolution.

For a more detailed explanation, see this answer:
[Specifying and saving a figure with exact size in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels)