# How to save correlation graph as png

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a code that looks like this:

```
corr = sdf.corr(method="spearman")
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')
```

I have an output of correlation graph. I saw online to use this code to save it as image

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.figure(figsize = (16,8))
sns.heatmap(sdf.corr(method='spearman'), annot=True, fmt='.4f', 
            cmap=plt.get_cmap('coolwarm'), cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation="horizontal")
plt.savefig('result.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

But this clogs the output like this:
[image]

How do I save this?

Edit:

Tried the answer below and it is showing this.

[image]

Comment: Check this answer and see if it helps you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
plt.savefig("result.png", dpi = 100)
```

Comment: It prints blank image

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following to save your image.

```
plt.matshow(data.corr())
plt.savefig('corr.png', dpi=300)
```

I would suggest you increase the figure size and then try to save it as an image. In your case, one possible reason can be that you are making use of sns.heatmap() and that is the reason it is not saving.

Answer (score 0):

1. `fig` and `ax` are not defined correctly.
   `plt.subplots()` and `plt.figure()` should not be simultaneously called.
   In your code, it is recommended that `plt.figure(figsize = (16,8))` be deleted and the parameter `figsize = (16,8)` be moved to `plt.subplots`.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (16,8))
sns.heatmap(sdf.corr(method='spearman'), annot=True, fmt='.4f', 
            cmap=plt.get_cmap('coolwarm'), cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation="horizontal")
plt.savefig('result.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

2. The figure size might be too small for the numbers to display. Try enlarge the figsize like

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20, 10))
sns.heatmap(sdf.corr(method='spearman'), annot=True, fmt='.4f', 
            cmap=plt.get_cmap('coolwarm'), cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation="horizontal")
plt.savefig('result.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

[image]

Comment: Please check the answer

Comment: Incomplete heatmap was a bug I came across before, which was caused by incompatible versions between seaborn and matplotlib. Update them both to the lastest versions and the output will hopefully be fine.