# How to change the size of image created by savefig (seaborn heatmap ) to 1000*1000 px?

Tags: python, seaborn

Trying to change the size of a plot. But somewhere happens a  leak and image instead of being 1000x1000 is 775x770  px. I know that pad tightens the figure. I expect the figure be of 1000x1000 without edges, borders, etc

```
w = 1000
    h = 1000

    plt.figure(figsize=(w/1000,h/1000), dpi=100)
    sn.heatmap(depthnp,  xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False,
               center=default, cmap=self.cmap, cbar=False)
    plt.savefig('tempFile.png', dpi=1000, bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches = 0)
```

Is there a way to make it fit the expected size?

Comment: Don't add `bbox_inches='tight'` which is designed to expand or crop the figure size to a tight fit around the plot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying and saving a figure with exact size in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels)

Comment: @mwaskom I don't need edges, but a figure itself

Comment: @TIIITAN that's what i used as example, but no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1)` would reduce the whitespace.  `plt.axis('off')` turns off the axes.

Also note that `figsize=(1,1)` might give strange results when working with text. `figsize=(10,10)` and `plt.savefig(..., dpi=100)` could work better.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

w = 1000
h = 1000
plt.figure(figsize=(w / 100, h / 100))
ax = sns.heatmap(gaussian_filter(np.random.rand(50, 50), 5), xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, cbar=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('tempFile.png', dpi=100, pad_inches=0)
```

[image: 1000x1000 bitmap]

Comment: thanx, I've created smth simular. what type of "wierd results" does it create?

Comment: A strange result would be that the default text wouldn't fit into the plot, it will look extremely large. Often, matplotlib will remove tick marks to try to make things fit.