# How can i output a Specific size image through the coordinate system in figure?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I wanna output a result image of the image processor, and found that the position of the output image had offset.I think this may be because of some size adaptation when the figure be saved.
I have tried the following code but they have not worked.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.4, 4.8), frameon=False)
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.savefig("./output.png", pad_inches=0)
plt.show()
```

As you can see,i set `figsize=(6.4, 4.8)`. What i wanna is to get a image which size is 680 x 400  and the image will be mapping from the plot figure range x=[0,640],y=[0,480].

How Do I get an image that corresponds one-to-one to the corresponding point in the coordinate system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13714720/7789963

Comment: @medium-dimensional Thank you very much！This is just what I need，now I can get on with my work. You saved my day