# Saved matplotlib size on pdf is larger than original figure

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, figsize

When checking matplotlib figure size is :

```
fig_width, fig_height = plt.gcf().get_size_inches()
print(fig_width, fig_height)
```

6.0 4.0
´<Figure size 3600x2400 with 0 Axes>´

One of the params to create the figure was:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 600
```

I save the figure with the following code:

```
plt.savefig("figure.pdf", format= 'pdf', bbox_inches="tight",dpi=600)
```

When checking resulting pdf size I can see it is larger than the original one:

[image]

I also tried saving the image without specifying dpi, but result was the same:

```
plt.savefig("figure.pdf", format= 'pdf', bbox_inches="tight")
```

I read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels), but could not find the answer.

How should I save the matploblig figure so that resulting pdf is desired size 6*4 inches and 600 dpi resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following line before `plt.savefig()` solved the issue:

```
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `bbox_inches="tight"`, which try to remove the white border but changes the fig size while doing so.

Instead, create your figure using `layout = 'constrained'` or `layout = 'tight'`:

```
fig = plt.figure(layout='constrained') 
plt.savefig("figure.pdf", dpi=600)
```

Comment: when entering the first line of your code, i get the error TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'layout'

Comment: @josepmaria What version of Matplotlib are you using?

Comment: @josepmaria Update `matplotlib` to the last version, or use `constrained_layout=True` instead of `layout=constrained`.

Comment: @jared current matplotlib version is 3.4.3

Comment: @josepmaria It looks like the `layout` argument was added around version 3.6. If you're going to stick to 3.4, use `constrained_layout=True`, as @Liris suggested.